# List of Appendices doesn't work in dissertation template

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I've been building my PhD dissertation over the past several months. I started with the template but I have progressively added numerous packages and snippets of code based on my needs. What I noticed recently is that the List of Appendices doesn't work.

Here is some content from my preamble, which comes from a template that was built 5 years ago by a graduate student I don't know. All of the documents I downloaded from [this website](http://grad.uwo.ca/current_students/thesis/formatting.html).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,
bibencoding=ascii,
citestyle=authoryear,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Next the preamble defines the thesis page style, sets up the page layout, defines margins, and defines a style for chapter epigraphs. Next, we have the following instructions from the template author:

```
\begin{document}
%% ***   NOTE   ***
%% You should put all of your '\newcommand', '\newenvironment', and
%% '\newtheorem's (in other words, all the global definitions that you
%% will need throughout your thesis) in a separate file and use
\input{commands}
```

So below I'll amend some of these commands but I can provide any of the content if needed.

```
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}%
%<details omitted>

\newenvironment{dedication}%
%<details omitted>

\newenvironment{preliminary}%
%<details omitted>

\newcommand{\qed}
%<details omitted>

\newcommand\isjoint[1]
%<details omitted>

\newcommand\isalt[1]
%<details omitted>

\newcommand\isdefinedsig[1]
%<details omitted>

\newcommand\isdefinedspinetitle[1]
%<details omitted>

\newcommand\coauthor[1]
%<details omitted>

\newcommand\acknowlege[1]
%<details omitted>

%<Next, about 20 lines define functions for the names of the supervisory committee and examination committe>

\newcommand{\makecoauthor}{
Type information about coauthorship here/}
\newcommand{\makeacknowlege} {
Type in acknowlegements here
} %These commands make space for a co-authorship statement and the acknowledgements.

%%%Here's where things get interesting:

\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{myappendices}{app}{\listappendixname}
\newcommand{\myappendices}[1]{}%
\addcontentsline{app}{myappendices}{#1}\par}

%Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
%<to be read again> 
%                  1
%l.125 \addcontentsline{app}{myappendices}{#1}
%                                            \par}
%You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
%Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
%are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
%
%! Too many }'s.
%l.125 \addcontentsline{app}{myappendices}{#1}\par}

%<The rest of these commands set up the template for the title page and examination certificate.>
```

I'm including the details above because my issues are related to the List of Appendices.

```
\begin{preliminary}

%% This generates the title page from the information given above.
\maketitle
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate of Examination}
\makecert
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Co-Authorship Statement}
%\coauthor{\makecoauthor}  %comment this out if none
%\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowlegements}
%\acknowlege{\makeacknowlege}   %as above
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\Large\begin{center}\textbf{Abstract}\end{center}\normalsize
%%  ***  Put your Abstract here.   ***
%% (150 words for M.Sc. and 350 words for Ph.D.)

This is a really silly abstract.

\vfill
\textbf{Keywords:} Time series analysis, data mining
\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\newpage
```

Here's the important part:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
\listofmyappendices\newpage

%I've left the rest in for good measure.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature}
\large List of Abbreviations, Symbols, and Nomenclature \normalsize
\newpage
\end{preliminary}
```

The relevant portion of the body is the instructions on how to insert the appendices:

```
%Appendices.
\begin{appendices}
\input{AppendixA}
\input{AppendixB}
\input{AppendixC}
\input{AppendixD}
\end{appendices}
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the list of appendices not to work?

Comment: Please combine your code snippets to be compilable! Have you testes that allthe given packages are neccessary to recreate the problem? What should we do with your `\input` commands? We do not have the "inputted" file so it is useless for us ...I hope I was able to give you an idea for what we need a minimal (not) working example.  Please help us to help you!  Where does `\begin{preliminary}` comes from?

Comment: I will run some tests and get back to you. Good suggestions! Sorry, newb here.

Comment: Off-topic comment: You've got already a bunch of questions and some of them have acceptable solutions, but you have not accepted none so far -- this is not how TeX.SX works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most likely in those two lines:

```
\newcommand{\myappendices}[1]{}%
\addcontentsline{app}{myappendices}{#1}\par}
```

whereas the template (see [westernthesis](http://grad.uwo.ca/doc/academic_services/thesis/latex/westernthesis.tex)) has

```
\newcommand{\myappendices}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{app}{myappendices}{#1}\par}
```

I.E. the outer right `}` of `\newcommand{\myappendices}[1]{%` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you! I never would have figured that out. I'll go sort out my other questions as well.

Comment: @AllanM: You're welcome -- and that's nice ;-)